# Store "label" of dropdown instead of "value" in table magento

Tags: magento

I have a problem regarding the storing of a dropdown values from my custom module. I have created the form in the backend to store "suburb", and another form to save "region". In this form for region there is a drop-down which values are populated from the table of suburb i.e suburb name. My problem is while saving this region the value of dropdown is stored in database table(i.e. '1','2') but i want to store the label(i.e suburb name selected) instead. How can I do that,Please could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this functionality using simple javascript code

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
<option value="1">label 1</option>
<option value="2">label 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="selectedMenu" id="selectedMenu" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

> ### JSFIDDLE Demo
>
> Here's [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/baigmirzashakir/q8N96/)!!

Answer (score 0):

Now, the main method called in the admin part for a dropdown is from this class: 
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table as seen from the source_model field above. 
The method is this one:

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setAttributeFilter($this->getAttribute()->getId())
                ->setStoreFilter($this->getAttribute()->getStoreId())
                ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                ->load()
                ->toOptionArray();
        }
        $options = $this->_options;
        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        }
        //print_r($options);
        return $options;
    }
```

Now, what this method does, is get all records for this model “ eav/entity_attribute_option_collection”, for our attribute_id and store_id 
then it populates an array with “label” and “value”.
You need to change source_model for your field in that table, set it to “eav/entity_attribute_source_table2”. so just copied the same class, gave it a new name, etc.

All you need to do is change that method

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true)
    {     
        $options[] = array('label' => '', 'value'=>'');
        $options[] = array('label' => 'Test1', 'value'=>'1');
        $options[] = array('label' => 'Test2', 'value'=>'2');
        $options[] = array('label' => 'Test3', 'value'=>'3');
        $options[] = array('label' => 'Test4', 'value'=>'4');
        $this->_options = $options;
        print_r($options);
        return $options;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dakshika Thanks for the response, i appreciate it but either you didn't understood me properly or i didn't understand you.my problem is i have to store the label of the dropdown from my form in admin panel to the region table,till now only the value of dropdown is being stored. If this could be achieved by your answer please clearify it more generally because i am new to it. thanx again